# Redux dispatch is not working only in mobile

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-saga

I'm using **Next.js, ts, redux, redux-saga, redux-wrapper** now. (All library is new version)
And I am working to load the recipe through an API connected to MongoDB.
Using **getServerSideProps** initially load recipes and when i clicked the button load more recipes. This is my Goal.

But this works only pc and Chrome mobile mode. In real mobile (IOS, Android), initially load is working but when button clicked dispatch is not working.
If it doesn't work in a PC environment, I will find out the cause, but I don't know the reason because it doesn't work only on mobile.

**/pages/index.tsx**

```js
const onClickMore = () => {
    setOpen(true);
    dispatch({type: LOAD_RECIPES_REQUEST});
  }

// ...some codes

export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(store => async () => {
  store.dispatch({type:LOAD_RECIPES_REQUEST});
  store.dispatch(END);
  await store.sagaTask.toPromise();
});
```

**/modules/recipe.ts**

```js
export const initialState: IrecipeInitialState = {
  mainRecipes: [],
  loadRecipesLoading: false,
  loadRecipesDone: false,
  loadRecipesError: null
}
export type IrecipeReducerState = typeof initialState;

export const LOAD_RECIPES_REQUEST = 'recipe/LOAD_RECIPES_REQUEST' as const;
export const LOAD_RECIPES_SUCCESS = 'recipe/LOAD_RECIPES_SUCCESS' as const;
export const LOAD_RECIPES_FAILURE = 'recipe/LOAD_RECIPES_FAILURE' as const;


export const loadRecipesRequestAction = () => {
  return{
    type:LOAD_RECIPES_REQUEST
  };
}

const recipe = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD_RECIPES_REQUEST:
      console.log("here1");
      return {
        ...state,
        loadRecipesLoading: true,
        loadRecipesDone: false,
        loadRecipesError: null,
    };
    case LOAD_RECIPES_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        mainRecipes: [...state.mainRecipes,...action.data],
        loadRecipesLoading: false,
        loadRecipesDone : true,
        loadRecipesError : null,
      }
    case LOAD_RECIPES_FAILURE:
      return{
        ...state,
        loadRecipesLoading: false,
        loadRecipesError : action.error,
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default recipe;
```

**/sagas/recipe.ts**

```js
function loadRecipesAPI(lastId: IloadRecipesAPI ) {
  return lastId ? axios.get(`/recipes?lastId=${lastId}`) : axios.get(`/recipes`);
}

function* loadRecipes(action: IloadRecipesSaga) {
  try {
      const result = yield call(loadRecipesAPI, action.data);
      yield put({
          type: LOAD_RECIPES_SUCCESS,
          data: result.data,
      });
  } catch (error: any) {
      yield put({
          type: LOAD_RECIPES_FAILURE,
          error: error.response.data
      });
  }
}

function* watchLoadRecipes() {
  yield takeEvery(LOAD_RECIPES_REQUEST,loadRecipes);
}

export default function* recipeSaga() {
  yield all([
    fork(watchLoadRecipes),
  ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found answer..
This is not redux, saga problem. This is axios.get problem.

I use `axios.defaults.baseURL` this with **localhost**, so when i use phone, axios is not working